# Create session from drop down list items

Tags: php, mysql, session, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop-down list that shows the members which have been added from the user. The script for this is this one:

```
<?php include('server.php'); ?>
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "geofence");
?>
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Add members</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>           
    </head>  
    <body>
    <div class="container">  
        <br /><br /> 
        <h2 align="center">Please, choose a family member</h2>
        <br /><br />                
        <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <form name="dropdown" action="" method="post">
                  <select name="choose" id="choose" width="150" style="width: 150px">
                  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Member</option>
    <?php
    $res=mysqli_query($connect,"select * 
                                from member 
                                where user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {  
    ?>
                    <option><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
                  </select>
                </form>
                <input type="button" name="ok" id="ok" class="btn btn-info" value="OK" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>  
    </html>
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#ok').click(function(){            
        $(location).attr('href', 'http://localhost/Houston/index.php') 
    });
});  
</script>
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to create a session ($_SESSION['member_id']) which refers to the name that is selected from the list. I have tried several things so far but with no success. An example  is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['choose'])) {
         if (count($errors)==0) {
                $query="SELECT * FROM member where name=".$_POST['choose']."";
                $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
                    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result);
                    $member_id=$row['member_id'];
                    $_SESSION['member_id'] = $row['member_id']; 
                }
         }
      }
```

I need the $_SESSION['member_id'] so I can use it on another file and populate my database. What is missing?

Comment: For one thing, you've an input that's outside the form.

Comment: 2nd, you're leaving yourself open to injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are posting data to `http://localhost/Houston/index.php`

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I changed it (put it inside the form) but the problem remains. Also I'm not really concerned about injection, it's just a school project.

Comment: @Arash Younesi you mean that I have to do something more with jquery?

Comment: No. just set `action` for your form and remove `onclick` action for `#ok` button

Comment: Did you do a `start_session()` in either of these code fragments somewhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes this is already set

Comment: Thank you guys for all the valuable feedback! There were many issues with this. Following the advice of Arash Younesi and the answer from Daniel I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the option tag, you have to specify de value of each option in the select tag , like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row["member_id"];?>"> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?> </option>
```

So, next you just have to declare the $_SESSION for your option value

```
if (isset($_POST['choose'])) {
       $_SESSION['member_id']=$_POST["choose"];
 }
```